# MVC Redirect won't work if I call it outside the main function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, controller

So, when I click a button - it hits submit. I manage to get the URL value fine. My issue is that hitting "RedirectingTime" function won't redirect the page. It just stops and displays a blank page. If I put it inside the Submit function then it works fine but I don't want to change my submit from a void to a redirect as I would like to also return a view if it errors.
Thanks!

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Submit(URLModel model)
    {

        string url = EmailEnd(model);

        if (url != "0")
        {
            RedirectingTime(url);
        }
        else
        {
            Error();
        }
    }


    public RedirectResult RedirectingTime(string url)
    {
        return Redirect(url);
    }

    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Based on the answer below - the working code is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(URLModel model)
    {

        string url = EmailEnd(model);

        if (url != "0")
        {
            return Redirect(url);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Error");
}
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Submit` action returning `void`. That will *always* result in a blank page, because void is essentially the same as `EmptyResult`.

The action you *hit* is what returns the result, not some action you call from it. Even though `RedirectingTime` returns a redirect, your `Submit` action never returns *that*, so the result is still `EmptyResult` and not `RedirectResult`.

Also, for what it's worth, it's atypical and unnecessary to explicitly set the type of the return value of the action. Virtually every MVC action signature should simply have `ActionResult` as the return. You can *actually* return anything with that, `RedirectResult`, `ViewResult`, `JsonResult`, etc.

Comment: Perfect. That explains why I wasn't getting anything. +1

Answer (score 1):

The crux of your problem is that your Submit action is not returning anything.  It has to return an ActionResult (or a derived form of ActionResult).  If you want to "Redirect" to another action on your controller, you use `RedirectToAction`.  You can use this with or without parameters as illustrated below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(URLModel model)
{

    string url = EmailEnd(model);

    if (url != "0")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("RedirectingTime", new { url = url });
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error");
    }
}

public RedirectResult RedirectingTime(string url)
{
    return Redirect(url);
}

public ActionResult Error()
{
    return View();
}
```